# What Advanced text tag should I be using to import images from a word document to Qualtrics?

Tags: survey, qualtrics

I want to create a survey using Qualtrics that has an image and a multiple-choice question asked based on the image. I am able to do this manually in Qualtrics using the rich content editor, But since I have a lot of such questions, I would like to automate it. I tried using the Advanced txt option (Shown below) to create a word document file of the required format but I am not sure how to add images in this document. I was trying to use the [[DB]] tag but I could not make it work. I thought of using the API addons but I am not clear on how to proceed with that as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
[[AdvancedFormat]]
[[Block:MC Block]]
[[Question:MC:SingleAnswer:Vertical]]
**(I need an image to be added here)**
Question 1
[[Choices]]
Choice 1
Choice 2
Choice 3
Choice 4

[[Question:MC:SingleAnswer:Vertical]]
**(I need an image to be added here)**
Question 2
[[Choices]]
Choice 1
Choice 2
Choice 3
Choice 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add html to display the image. For example:

```
[[Question:MC]]
[[ID:Q1]]
<div style="text-align:center"><img src="https://example.com/myimage.png" alt="myimage"></div>
[[Choices]]
```

Some other things:

1. SingleAnswer:Vertical is the default so you don't need to specify it
2. You should specify the question label (e.g. [[ID:Q1]] for each quesiton
3. You need an additional carriage return after [[AdvancedFormat]] and [[Block:MC Block]]